# store output from here document to a variable

Tags: shell, heredoc

here is my code

```
ssh $target 2>/dev/null << 'ENDSSH'
echo xxx;
ENDSSH
```

But I want to store the output from the here doc, like this:

```
var=`ssh $target 2>/dev/null << 'ENDSSH'
    echo xxx;
    ENDSSH`
```

But this is not a valid implementation, can anyone help?

Comment: Use $() instead of `` as they latter has issues with several things.  Also, the heredoc name has to be on a line on its own, so the closing ) would need to be on the next line

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh password-less login setup, then a command substitution construct would be a better approach here:-

```
var=$( ssh $target "echo xxxx" )
```

Comment: No, there is a complex logic inside 'ENDSSH', so i need to keep 'ENDSSH'

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean by "this is not a valid implementation"? Are you getting error while running? If yes, post the details.